# Python Include Custom Modules

Tags: python, module, scrapy

Making a basic python scraper...can't figure how to include a module that I've made into another module. Getting: "No module error". Here is the file structure:[image]

code for indeed_spider.py:

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join, MapCompose
from ..scraper_app import items

class IndeedSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "indeed"
    allowed_domains = ["indeed.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=security&l="]

    deals_list_xpath = '//div[@class="row result"]/td[@class="snip"]'
    item_fields = {
        'title': '',
        'location': '',
        'blurb': '',
        'pay': '',
        'description': ''
    }
```

Error occurs when I run python indeed_spider.py...I'm sure there's some basic understanding of python that I'm missing, I'm very new to the language. Thanks! :)

Comment: Please post the full exact error message you're having. Also, just a guess - if you don't have those - try creating empty `__init__.py` files in the module directories (`scraper_app` and `spiders`). Not sure if it would help - don't know how exactly Scapy imports its modules, but if it's normal Python import mechanisms, then it may.

Comment: This could be usefull: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath/471168#471168

Comment: I created the _init_.py files, still getting same error, working on adding to PythonPath

Comment: I second this question and cant't find a proper solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

When using Scrapy, you run your spiders running `scrapy crawl <spider name>` from the root folder (the one containing the `scrapy.cfg` file).

If you generate your spider project with `scrapy startproject`, you should already get an `items.py` where you can define your `Item` subclasses.